# Ajax call to wiktionary.org to retrieve information on one specific language

Tags: ajax, wiktionary

To get information about a word in Wiktionary, I can make an Ajax call to the following URL at wiktionary.org: [https://en.wiktionary.org/w/api.php?action=parse&format=json&prop=text|revid&callback=?&page=слово](https://en.wiktionary.org/w/api.php?action=parse&format=json&prop=text%7Crevid&callback=?&page=%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE), where `слово` is the word of interest.

This will return a JSON object with the format...

```
{ "parse":
  { "title": "\u0442\u044b"
  , "pageid":96216
  , "revid":38162039
  , "text":{
      "*": <HTML string>
    }
  }
}
```

... where `<HTML string>` contains information on the given word, in all the languages that Wiktionary associates with the word. In the case of the word `слово`, this means

- Bulgarian
- Macedonian
- Old Church Slavonic
- Russian
- Serbo-Croatian
- Ukrainian

How can I change the URL for the Ajax call so that it only returns data for a single language (for example: Russian)?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible as in terms of Wiktionary each word is a page with wiki-formatted text. It's not structured as a JSON or any other machine readable data structure format. Though, they have a [convention](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wiktionary:Entry_layout#Entry_name) which every page is supposed to follow. According to it, each page should have level 2 headings with word's language. So, you can parse the wikitext to extract only the data for the language you want by looking for such a heading and taking only the data below it.